# Applescript simple open save file snippet?

Tags: applescript

I just need a snippet to open and then save a file. It's an illustrator PDF with linked artwork, problem being the linked files do not update unless I open then save the file and I am having to do this sooooo many times it's making my brain explode.

Comment: I little more precision would be nice. Perhaps writing out the pseudo code could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be straightforward. I tested the following snippet in Illustrator CS3 (13.0.2) on Mac OS X 10.6.8.

```
set theFiles to choose file with prompt "Select the files" of type {"pdf"} with multiple selections allowed

tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    repeat with theFile in theFiles
        open theFile without dialogs
        save current document in theFile as pdf
    end repeat
end tell
```

The `choose file` command (which prompts the user to locate one or more files) is just one way of obtaining a list of files. You could just as well use

`tell app "Finder" to set theFiles to every document file of folder "Macintosh HD:Full:Path:To:Your:Folder" whose file type begins with "pdf"`

if you want to get all PDF files inside a specific folder.